# WordPress: what is the workflow to publish?

Tags: wordpress

I'm new to WP and these were my steps:

- I downloaded wp and I installed it (I also installed a pair of
  plugins and a theme...).
- I created a git repository in a remote host and i pushed
  the wp project. In the remote host, I cloned the git repo to
  `/var/www/my_wp_project`.
- I request the url
  `http://my_remote_host/my_wp_project`, but it asked me about **installing wp
  again**...
- Well after installed wp again, the theme **is not the same
  as in local**...!

Can anyone give some advices?

Comment: You'd probably get some answers at http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/